# Highcharts - Remove "hover" state from chart point (that was set externally)

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I created a combination of chart and table. Took me for ever to be able to hover on one column and trigger the corresponding tooltip. Everything works fine except that the points in the chart (the ones that once were triggered by hovering on a table column) remain with the hover state.

In the image, it's clear what I need to accomplish. I need that, everytime I hover on another column, all the previous point are set to "normal" instead of "hover" (I doubt that's the real way to call it)

So in the image:

- the blue arrow points to the right state (when the column is hovered on)
- the red arrow points to the wrong state (once you hovered on a column but then hovered another)
- the green arrow points to the state that all the points except the one in focus, should be

How it should be:
[image]

PS: if you hover on any of the cells, or all of them, they all get the "hover" status, but if you hover on 1 point of the chart, the rest of the points get the "normal" status, which is what I need to accomplish.

The code can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2549acmt/8/) or here:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="section_status_chart"></div>
<div id="section_status_table1">
  <table id="section_status_table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Apr 12</th>
        <th>Apr 13</th>
        <th>Apr 14</th>
        <th>Apr 15</th>
        <th>Apr 16</th>
        <th>Apr 17</th>
        <th>Apr 18</th>
        <th>Apr 19</th>
        <th>Apr 20</th>
        <th>Apr 21</th>
        <th>Apr 22</th>
        <th>Apr 23</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Approved</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">2,658</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,554</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,653</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,997</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-966</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,087</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,434</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,112</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,546</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-750</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">998</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">157</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Conditionally approved</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,543</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-1,634</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,976</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">2,643</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,007</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,114</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,435</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-841</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,182</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,221</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">2,009</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-201</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Referred</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-652</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,654</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,262</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,621</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-116</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,143</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,004</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,965</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">2,531</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-1,645</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,442</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-1,967</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rejected</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,144</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,523</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,616</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-553</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,039</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,343</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,300</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,533</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-882</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,161</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">2,030</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-1,932</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="table-footer">
        <td>Total</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-652</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,654</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,262</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,621</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-116</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,143</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,004</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,965</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">2,531</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-1,645</td>
        <td class="font-green-meadow">1,442</td>
        <td class="font-red-intense">-1,967</td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hn6Ltvx0/), but this is the main code to fix the issue:

```
...
if (pointIndex > -1) {
  for(var i = 0; i < section_status_chart.series[0].data.length; i++) {
    section_status_chart.series[0].data[i].setState('');
  }
  section_status_chart.series[0].data[pointIndex].setState('hover');
  section_status_chart.tooltip.
    refresh(section_status_chart.series[0].data[pointIndex]);
}
...
```

Set the state back to `''` for all points before setting the state on the point associated with the column. There's probably a cleaner solution than the `for` loop I've written, but this is the main idea.

P.S. This is a really nice feature you've made!

Comment: @j-titus you're awesome :D that solved the problem! :)

Thanks for your time!